# Dart Flutter: Function not executing

Tags: function, flutter, dart, execute

I am new to Dart & Flutter, I am trying to test `Future` functionality. I wrote a short `async` function, in which two `Future` objects are nested.
**Problem:** The function does not execute, and when I try to attribute it to a variable I get an error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.` and `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`.
Here is the code: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
  @override
  _ChoseLocationState createState() => _ChoseLocationState();
}

class _ChoseLocationState extends State<ChoseLocation> {
  int counter = 0;
  
  void simulateRequest() async {

    // first future holds family name
    String famNameFunc = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      String famName = 'Shanshi';
      return famName;
    });


    // second future holds first name
    String compName = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
      String fstName = 'Yoshi';
      String compName = '$fstName - $famNameFunc';
      return compName;
    });

    print(compName);
  }

  dynamic funcex = simulateRequest();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('This is the initial state.');
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('This is the build function processing.');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text('Set Location'),
          centerTitle: true,
          ),
        body: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            counter++;
          });
        },
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Counter is: $counter'),
        ),
      );
  }
}```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmvY9.png
````

Comment: can you copy/paste your code instead of screenshot of it?

Comment: @JideGuru Of course, one sec.

Comment: did you try calling it in initState?

Comment: @JideGuru I want to execute it independently of ```initState```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class ChoseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  ChoseLocation({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _ChoseLocationState createState() => _ChoseLocationState();
}

class _ChoseLocationState extends State<ChoseLocation> {
  int counter = 0;
  
  void simulateRequest() async {

    // first future holds family name
    String famNameFunc = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      String famName = 'Shanshi';
      return famName;
    });


    // second future holds first name
    String compName = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
      String fstName = 'Yoshi';
      String compName = '$fstName - $famNameFunc';
      return compName;
    });

    print(compName);
  }

//   dynamic funcex = simulateRequest();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    simulateRequest();
    print('This is the initial state.');
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('This is the build function processing.');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text('Set Location'),
          centerTitle: true,
          ),
        body: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            counter++;
          });
        },
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Counter is: $counter'),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

You need to call `simulateRequest()` inside a method example `initState`, and since it doesnt return anything then you cannot assign it to a variable.

Comment: Same thing, it does not get executed.

Comment: it will get executed when initState is called, also why are u using Future.delayed? You are just assigning a value to a string variable why the Future.delayed?

Comment: Hey man could you help me?
I passed the ```simulateRequest()``` function to a new class named ```SimReq``` and placed it in a new file and then imported it.

When I call for this function inside the *choselocation.dart* file, I get an error.
Basically what I want to know, is how to call for a method placed in an imported class.

Comment: please ask it another question including the code of both files and link it here so i can check it

Comment: I can only post once every 90 mins, I will leave the URL once I can.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502376/dart-flutter-how-to-call-for-a-class-method-inside-another-class

Answer (score 2):

`simulateRequest` has a return type of `void`, so if you'r trying to store this function in the variable you shouldn't put parenthesis. If you use the parenthesis you'll be running the function and assigning it's returned value which is `void` to the variable `funcex` and thats why u're getting: `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

```
      @override
  void initState() {
    dynamic funcex = simulateRequest;
    funcex();
    super.initState();
    print('This is the initial state.');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 1st function does not invokes performTask function. But 2nd function invoked performTask and executes as expected. Below is an illustration.

Conclusion - Try including parentheses ***( )*** at the end of your invoking void function

```
 // 1st Function - Not working
 void someFunction(int A, void Function()? performTask) {
    if (A == 1) {

      // performTask did not invoked 
      performTask;
    } else {
     // Do something else
    }
  }

  // 2nd Function - Working
  void someFunction(int A, void Function()? performTask) {
    if (A == 1) {
      if (performTask != null) {

      // performTask is invoked 
        performTask();
      }
    } else {
     // Do something else
    }
  }
```