# Dart & Flutter: How to call for a class method inside another class

Tags: function, class, flutter, dart, execute

new to Dart here, sorry in advance if this is a redundant question; I couldn't find the answer.
I created a function `simulateRequest` and then passed it to its own class `SimReq` and saved it in a file on its own.
I imported the class in the main file, but when I try to execute it, I get an error, here is the class code:

```
class SimReq {
  void simulateRequest() async {

    // first future holds family name
    String famNameFunc = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      String famName = 'Shanshi';
      return famName;
    });


    // second future holds first name
    String compName = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
      String fstName = 'Yoshi';
      String compName = '$fstName - $famNameFunc';
      return compName;
    });

    print(compName);
  }
    SimReq(){
    simulateRequest();
 }
}
```

and here is the main file code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wtap/pages/simreq.dart';

class ChoseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChoseLocationState createState() => _ChoseLocationState();
}

class _ChoseLocationState extends State<ChoseLocation> {
  int counter = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('This is the initial state.');
    SimReq.simulateRequest(); // I am trying to execute the function here.
  }
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @pedropimont I just added a comment, it explains it better. 
Error : ```Instance member 'simulateRequest' can't be accessed using static access.```

Comment: Create an instance of `SimReq` and call the method simulateRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate an object of the SimReq class if you want access to its methods like:

```
SimReq simReq = SimReq();
simReq.simulateRequest();
```

or use the `static` keyword to make this function accessible outside of this class

```
static void simulateRequest() async {
```

Answer (score 0):

without instance

```
 simReq().simulateRequest();
```